# Java - Cannot Connect To MySQL, However No Error Message Being Displayed

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to allow users to login to their own account.
The details are stored in a MySQL database, and there is a php file that helps direct, and validate their input.

However, when I launch the code nothing happens.
I am unsure of where I have made my mistake, I've been editing and rewording the code for three days now without any result.

I would appreciate any help.

Update: it appears the error may be with String link as catch is printing the website address

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;



import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private TextView statusField,roleField;
    private Context context;


    //flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
    public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView statusField,TextView roleField) {
        this.context = context;
        this.statusField = statusField;
        this.roleField = roleField;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try{
                String username = (String)arg0[0];
                String password = (String)arg0[1];

                String link = "https://*/*/LoginFile.php";
                String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                wr.write( data );
                wr.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.statusField.setText("Login Successful");
        this.roleField.setText(result);
    }
}
```

**The Code is then submitted via the MainActivity**

```
public void loginPost(View view){
        String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
        method.setText("Post Method");
        new SigninActivity(this,status,role).execute(username,password);
        method.setText(username);

    }
```

**MANIFEST**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.*.loginsystem" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="loginsystem"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.*.loginsystem.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How about using a debugger? (NB: sending clear text password like you are doing is not a good idea)

Comment: Hi RC, I'm currently coding in android studio, the debugger hasn't returned any results. (It is possible I may be misreading or using it), I appreciate the coding isn't well implemented its my first time so im just trying to understand the basics.

Comment: are you sure you're unable to connect to the database?  Are you sure you're not returning an empty string because you get a zero-length response?  What sorts of things do you see happening on the server side?  Are you sure the server sends a response at all?

Comment: @DanO How would I be able to test whether im submitting an empty string? In terms of the php their are no errors, which is why im so confused.

Comment: @FrankN.SteinHi Frank I meant like a MySQL database, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: From the access log, can you confirm that you are receiving the correct request?

Comment: @Bonatti The log isnt displaying any errors at all.

Comment: I do not mean on the device, I meant on the server. Is the server yours or not? If it is, then check the access.log from it, and check if you are receiveing the request. Also, I just realized that the link you are forming is missing the `?` char, after the php and the NamePairValues

Comment: Hi @Bonatti the server unfortunately does not belong to me, sorry where should the ? char be?

Comment: Ok then, are you connecting the device in wifi? if so, install wireshark, and capture the package you are sending. Check if it is valid. (Also, check my last comment, as I editted the end of it)... are you making a GET request? if so, the link should be [host]/[uri].php?var1=val1&var2=val2

Comment: Hi @Bonatti I am attempting to use the android emulator to connect. The code is meant to be sending a POST value. However I have inspected my php code and both $username and $password  are showing as undefined variable

Comment: While debugging your application, do arg[0] and arg[1] have values? post your manifest, and the call to the asynctask you are using.

Comment: @Bonatti I have ran the debugger and both both arg[0] and arg[1] have values. Is there a way of exporting my manifest to stack overflow?

Comment: Just copy paste the content on the editted question, then erase whatever you dont want us to see. (and add 4 blank spaces for automattic editing on each line)

Comment: @Bonatti Thank you VERY much for taking the time to talk to me very much appreciate it, I have updated my original question to include the manifest.